# Distance from centre point to other points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance

I have a question of something I actually thought was pretty simple...I have a few points around a centre point. Now I want to know the distance from each point to the centre point. Is it possible to do this without using the simple measurement tool. I mean, is there something that gives me "automatically" all the distances with just one query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Distance Matrix** function:

(from QGIS 2.2)

*Vector* > *Analysis Tools* > *Distance matrix*

or select it from *Processing Toolbox*

[image: Distance matrix]

Select the same point layer and it will calculate the distances between **each** point. You can then simply scroll or filter out your centre point to see the distances from the centre point to all the others in the layer.

Comment: you'll find distance matrix moved in Processing Toolbox

Comment: Thanks @LuigiPirelli, I should have mentioned that I was using QGIS 2.2 so the Distance matrix function is available from both the interface menu and the Processing Toolbox

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean with one query?

try to create a command/script using this suggestion:

get the geometry for the center feature and use QgsGeometry.distance() method http://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a9971f1e9c56cdf57c06017ec64e70151 
looping to all other point geometries

regards